# Why there is no main() method in android?

Tags: java, android

A Java program execution starts from main() method. Right? Since Android apps run on Java, Then why we didn't create a main() method in Android studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one, but you don't need to see it. Android takes care of threading and keeping threads organized for you, see [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/threads.html).

Moreover, the entry point for an activity is the `onCreate()` method, so all initialization is normally done in there. The first activity run by your app is normally specified in the [manifest](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=launcher%20activity%20android%20studio&oq=launcher%20activity&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.3012j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) file under the launcher keyword.

See [here](https://medium.com/@martinomburajr/android-internals-1-how-android-starts-your-main-activity-8fcf80e65222) to know more about how android runs the launcher activity.

Comment: Can you explain little more?

Comment: The article I referenced has a nice image showing the steps from calling the main() function in the ActivityThread class to calling the onCreate() function from an activity. It's pretty neat :)